# Is "layout" the same as "layout resource" in Android Studio? How can I programmingly create an XML layout resource?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am really confused by these two concepts. I have known "layout resource" refer to some XML format files such as "activity_main.xml", and inside an XML file there is a layout. So "layout" and "layout resource" may be different, I assume.

Today when I am using `inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)` , I don't know how I can get the ID of the "resource" (aka the XML file) , because I just programmingly create a new layout for ListView to display items, and I can only get the ID of the new layout by using `mylayout.setId(View.generateViewId())` . But I don't know the ID of the "resource", since I never create an XML file. Is the ID of a layout equal to the ID of its XML file?

So the question is here: when I only create a layout programmingly, how can I get its XML file? Should I create a XML file rather than a layout? If so, how can I make a new XML file programmingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access the `id` of your xml file through: `int id = R.layout.activity_main`

Note that this `id` is associated with the xml file itself. To access the id of a specific view within your layout file, replace `layout` with `id`: `R.id.my_view_id`.

For example, if you want to inflate `my_layout.xml`, you can pass `R.layout.my_layout` in the `resource` parameter of `inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`.

When you're *inflating* a layout at run-time, you are using an *existing* xml file to create your layout. A `layout resource` is a `layout`. Layout is just an abstraction to represent your UI. It does not refer to anything specific.

Also, you cannot 'create' an xml layout programmatically (rather you shouldn't) to generate your UI at run-time. But, you can create a *view* or a set of views contained within a `ViewGroup` programmatically.

Comment: To add on to this: All "layouts" are `ViewGroups`. Conceptually, they are something that goes _on the screen_. A layout resource describes the arrangement of `Views` within a `ViewGroup`, but it is not, in itself, something that goes _"on the screen"_.